# Symfony VarDumper Doctrine Sub Objects

Tags: symfony, data-dumper, object-dumper

When i use VarDumper of Symfony (symfony/var-dumper) to dump an Doctrine object and do have collection of subobject but the dumper dont display those sub-objects ?

Is it normal ?

I use :

```
        echo '<pre>';
    \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($order, 5);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Cloner/Data.html#method_withMaxDepth Maybe helps.

Comment: This is not symfony varDumper, it's doctrine dump.http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using symfony dump but in your code you have a doctrine dump.

Despite that the 'dump' only show sub objects if they are not lazy loaded.

Comment: Sorry for real i dump with this 'dump($order)' but it doest not work and subobjects not showed so i use the code below.